# Set Render Target usage

Tags: unity, opengl, shaders, directx, glsl

I am using Unity and I have some difficulties about understanding the way Set Render Target works and how it can behave with the shaders.

Is it possible to render a shader pass in multiple render targets ? How ?
As this behaviour seems to be linked with all rendering platforms and not only Unity, any help is welcome.

Thanks !